# Where can see messages generated by blk_add_cgroup_trace_msg/blk_add_trace_msg?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to see the log messages generated by blk-throttle. It uses function like throtl_log(sq, "schedule timer. delay=%lu jiffies=%lu", expires - jiffies, jiffies);
The definition of throtl_log is

```
#define throtl_log(sq, fmt, args...)    do {                \
    struct throtl_grp *__tg = sq_to_tg((sq));           \
    struct throtl_data *__td = sq_to_td((sq));          \
                                    \
    (void)__td;                         \
    if (likely(!blk_trace_note_message_enabled(__td->queue)))   \
        break;                          \
    if ((__tg)) {                           \
        blk_add_cgroup_trace_msg(__td->queue,           \
            tg_to_blkg(__tg)->blkcg, "throtl " fmt, ##args);\
    } else {                            \
        blk_add_trace_msg(__td->queue, "throtl " fmt, ##args);  \
    }                               \
} while (0)
```

But I don't know where/how I can see these messages.

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.4/source/kernel/trace/Kconfig#L643) you need [blktrace user space tools](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/axboe/blktrace.git/) - or alternatively read `trace_pipe` in sysfs (see also the linked docs)